# Navigator pushReplacementNamed loads screen twice in Flutter app

Tags: flutter

Inside Flutter app I have MaterialApp with list of named routes and bottom navigation bar with few tabs. On one of tabs I have button with this code on tap

```
Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed(MyRouteName);
```

For some reason target screen is loaded few times (it can be seen on screen) and it's `initState()` method is also called at least twice. Why is it happening and what can be done with it?

Comment: Are you sure the `onTap()` method i.e. where you are calling the `pushReplacementNamed` method, is being called only once?

Comment: yes, they called once

Comment: well, you will have to provide more details,maybe some code,and flutter version...

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem too, I solved it by going back with Navigator.of (context).pop Actually, the solution may vary depending on your status as the route. I suggest you try alternative methods.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

```
Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(MyRouteName,(Route<dynamic> route) => false);
```